# Want to clear the listview item permanently?

Tags: android, listview

I want to clera the listview item from the screen when pressing the clear all button. So I used the function m_adapter.clear(); It's clearing the items from the screen. But when I again coming back to the app after exit, those views again coming back. I need to clear them permanently. Can anybody help me in this problem?

Code snippet is as follows:

```
case R.id.deleteAll:{
        m_adapter.clear();
            }
```

Comment: **But when I again coming back to the app after exit** means if you re-open the app again ?

Comment: If yes, onCreate() will be called in default activity, it will create all your views again. Then you will get all list items. Whatever you clear is eligible for current running process only. If you re-open it, again new process will be created. please check it.

Comment: Yes,that is correct. So what should I do to avoid this problem? I am very new to this programming, please help me out of this problem.

Comment: Please read above comment. You are thinking its a problem. its not a problem, its a general thing about a process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to remove and clear your listview permanently  your adapter.clear() will not work.

The actual meaning of this method is to clear your listview and not the listview items.

What you actually have to do is to remove all the elements from the array which you are using to populate the listview.

So this is the only way which will ensure you that your listview will not be loaded with data even when come back to your activity and getting out of it.

If not you will have to call your clear() each and every time you enter your activity, thus making it to look like as if there is not data present.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to clear the source of your listview data, then refresh the listview. That way, when you reopen the activity the data will not be redisplayed as it won't exist anymore.

Eg. If the listview is populated from a database, delete the data from the database, then refresh the listview.